# property of two numbers such that their exponential and product are the same

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is a equation:

$$ a^b = ab$$

[ that is, $a$ raised to $b$ is equal to $a$ times $b$ ]

Find all real values of $a$ and $b$ where $a$ is not equal to zero, $b$ is not
 equal to one.

[Difficulty]
 Two variables can be solved only if two distinct equations are
 provided describing the relationship between them. However, here only
 one equation is provided in which two variables exist and the
 challenge is to find all such sets of real numbers that satisfy the
 given relationship.

Hint: Infinite many such values satisfy the above

[Thoughts]
 Let $b = a^k$

then the given equation becomes

$$a^{a^k} = a \cdot a^k$$

or $a^k = k+1$ which means, $a^k - k = 1$ for all $a$ and $k$ where $a$ is a variable and $k$ can be a constant starting from say $0$.

Let $a =1$, $k = 0$ which satisfies the above equation $1^0 - 0 =1$.
 Accordingly $a=1$, $b=1$
 Let $a =2$, $k = 1$ then $2 ^1 - 1 = 1$ also satisfy the condition.
Accordingly $a=2$, $b=1$
 Let $a=\sqrt3$ , $k=2$, then $(\sqrt3)^2 - 2 = 1$ and accordingly
  $a= \sqrt{3}$, $b = 3$

Another set of such numbers that satisfy the above condition is $\frac{9}{4}$
 and $\frac{3}{2}$ as $(\frac{9}{4})^{\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{9}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{2}$.

In general, all $a$ and $k$ where $a= p^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and $k=n$ satisfy  the
 above condition for all $p \in \mathrm{R}$.

Please check this and let me know if my approach is correct. Thanks.

In general, all $a$ and $k$ where $a=p^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and $k=n$ satisfy
   the above condition for all $p \in \mathrm{R}$.

I mean,

For any real number $p$, there is an $n$ such that $a = p^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and
   $b = a^n$ will be a solution.

Please check this and let me know if my approach is correct. Thanks.

Comment: You decided to try expressing $b$ as a power $a^k$ of $a$.  You then get somewhat distracted with arguing special cases, and finally you introduce a new variable $p$.  But if we are dealing with $p \gt 0$, then $a = p^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and $b = a^n$.  Thus $p=b$ and we get nothing new.  Try letting $a$ be a power of $b$, and the Answer of TonyK should appear quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given any positive $b \ne 1$, just let $a = b^{1/(b-1)}$.